# problems with spinner in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

We are making a voice guided package and have come across a problem while implementing voice guidance in a unit converter.

We want the user to say to the system about what type of conversion he wants to make. For this purpose we provide the user with the set of choices that can be obtained from the following code segment:

```
 SpinnerUnit.performClick()
```

This code segment shows the various options like:

1. Temperature
2. Weight
3. Pressure
4. Etc...

However, once the user enters the command using his voice, the corresponding option gets selected but the spinner's view obtained from the `Spinner.performClick()` is still visible to the user.

What can we do to take this view to the background?

Answer (score 0):

`Spinner` does not offer a `dismiss` method which could help you to take away the popped-up window. However, as an alternate, I would suggest you to make use of `Dialog` and show your options inside. Once and option is selected, you may simply call its `dismiss` method to finish the window.